# what does the model structure look like when I use LoRA on a model fine-tuned by LoRA

Tags: huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, peft

I am fine-tuning a model using LoRA, and caused by curiosity, I performed another fine-tuning using LoRA on the already fine-tuned model.

codes is as follows:

```
model = AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM.from_pretrained("bigscience/mt0-large")
model = PeftModel.from_pretrained(model, "./mt0_lora1")
peft_config = LoraConfig(task_type=TaskType.SEQ_2_SEQ_LM, inference_mode=False, r=8, lora_alpha=32,
                         lora_dropout=0.1)
model = get_peft_model(model, peft_config)

...
training process
...

model.save_pretrained('./mt0_lora2')
```

I'm curious about what the model mt0_lora2 trained at this moment will look like in terms of its structure

I used the code print(model) to get the structure of this model and the output is too big to read. Due to LLM and transformers is totally new to me, I had no more solution.